# Consecutive calls testing in Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have simple service

```java
package net.betlista;

import java.util.List;

public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    MyDao dao;

    public void saveAll(final List<Integer> list) {
        for (final int i : list) {
            dao.save(i);
        }
    }

    void setDao(final MyDao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

}
```

and DAO

```java
package net.betlista;

public class MyDaoImpl implements MyDao {

    public void save(final Integer i) {
        // do nothing, ok for tests
    }

}
```

and I want to test with Mockito that when I call `service.saveAll()`, that `save()` call is called for all instances in list:

```java
package net.betlista;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.InOrder;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

public class MyServiceTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        final MyDao daoMock = Mockito.mock(MyDao.class);
        final MyServiceImpl service = new MyServiceImpl();
        service.setDao(daoMock);

        final List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);

        service.saveAll(list);

        // not working, it's ok, should fail
        //        Mockito.verify(daoMock).save(Matchers.eq(1));
        //        Mockito.verify(daoMock).save(Matchers.eq(1));

        final InOrder inOrder = Mockito.inOrder(daoMock);
        inOrder.verify(daoMock).save(1);
        inOrder.verify(daoMock).save(1); // change 1 to 2 to fix test

        Mockito.verify(daoMock);
    }

}
```

the commented part is not working = it passes, but should fail.

Using `InOrder`, works but in fact I'm not interested in order (for example if using set instead of list, order is not known).

Any idea, or I'm just trying to do something senseless?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to test with Mockito that when I call service.saveAll(), that save() call is called for all instances in list

OK, then how about this:

```
service.saveAll(list);

for (int i:list)
{
    Mockito.verify(daoMock).save(Matchers.eq(i));
}
```

I'm not entirely sure why you think the commented out lines should fail, but I'm guessing that its because you want to make sure its only called once?  If so, then the reason it passes it because it has only been called once, however, your test code is verifying twice that it was only called once which isn't much use.  The above code will verify that the save method was called once (and only once) for each item in the list.

Comment: notice that in the commented code, the OP is testing for `1` twice. The loop will not fix this issue.

Comment: @JohnB I suspect this answer is a replacement for everything after `service.saveAll(list)`.

Comment: Yes, Duncan is correct. I've edited the code snippet to clarify.

Comment: True, but the OP (for some reason) is attempting to have the test fail when verifying with a call of `1` two times. Using `verify(1)` twice does not cause the test to fail as desired by the OP.

Comment: Yes, but my point is that calling ``verify(1)`` twice is a non-sensical thing to do and most likely the wrong implementation of a possibly valid test condition.  It is the equivalent of calling ``assertEquals(...)`` twice in a row (assuming no side effects).

Comment: Ok, I didn't realize that calling verify(1) twice is same assert. And the test should fail when added  `Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(daoMock);` after the for loop.

Comment: Yes, but what if 1 occurs twice in the list?  Then you will end up calling `verify ... (1)` twice.  Doesn't seem like nonsense to me, except that it will make this answer fail.

Comment: If 1 occurs twice in the list, the the above code will intentionally fail as we are explicitly stating that we expect one and only one call with 1 as the parameter.  If we expect more than one call with 1 as the parameter then we need to restructure the expectation/verification:  e.g. ``verify(daoMock, times(2)).save(1)`` or ``verify(daoMock, atLeast(1)).save(1)``

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this is with an `ArgumentCaptor`.

```
service.saveAll(list);

ArgumentCaptor<Integer> values = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Integer.class);
verify(daoMock, times(list.size())).save(values.capture());
assertEquals(list, values.getAllValues());
```

The `ArgumentCaptor` gives you access to all of the values that were ever passed to this method.  So there's no need to worry about whether this method was called "extra" times; and no problem in the case where the same value occurs twice in the original list.

Comment: It all comes down to what the test is really trying to achieve.  There are many times when it is important to test that a method was called only once for a particular parameter.  If ``save`` is an intensive call to a database, then it would be nice if the test failed if we made redundant calls to the database.

Comment: No, @ChrisKnight I think you may have misunderstood me.  You can check `values.getAllValues()` after this test.  You can see if there are "redundant" calls in there, for whatever definition of redundant is appropriate.  This effectively means you're going to do the detailed verification yourself directly from the list, rather than from a series of calls to `verify`.  It is more flexible and more powerful, in _every_ case.

Comment: Well, flexible I'll give you, but I'd argue it's less readable for straightforward cases.  I'd rather use Mockito's simple intention-revealing API in such situations.

Comment: I also found this approach extremely useful for cases, when thousands of invocation with different arguments need to be checked. Checking that in regular 'for' loop takes unreasonable time

Answer (score 1):

```
 Mockito.verify(daoMock, Mockito.times(2)).save(Matchers.eq(1));
```

Since you are verifying the same value, use `times()`

However, the better way to test that there are exactly the number of invocations you want is to use `verifyNoMoreInteractions`

So the test would be like this:

```
 verify(daoMock).save(1);
 verify(daoMock).save(2);
 verifyNoMoreInteractions(daoMock);
```

Comment: This is a good answer. In the longer term, the OP should probably adopt a looping pattern (as per [Chris' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20193983/474189)).

Comment: Concur, loop is the way to go

Comment: `Mockito.verify(daoMock, Mockito.times(2)).save(1);` is more readable - no need for the argument matcher.